# migrating/replacing app from phonegap to brand new ios & android native apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Actually I have a phonegap app that i want to rewrite in native code for iOs & Android. So I don't want that when i release the new version actual users have to download it again, re-install and delete the phonegap version. 
I research a little bit about this and i figure that i have to name the bundle identifier as the old one, and sign with the same credentials, and a similar process in android.
Does somebody have experience in this process and can actually give me a hint on what not to forget as i am starting to code the new apps at the moment?
Thank you guys very much!!

F.

Comment: So long as your bundle id is the same, you pretty much cant go wrong. if anything else is out of place, you would get notified about it when trying to upload to the app store (eg version numbers, provisioning/signing profiles etc which can be corrected)

Comment: Thanks Fonix, do you have any experience in doing this in Android?

Comment: i havent personally done an android app upload to the play store, but i have worked on android projects and i believe its the same, just need you applicationId in your gradle file to be the same id as you had in your phonegap project, and your version code needs to just be higher than the last one

Comment: Thanks for the info Fonix. With this in mind i can start coding ASAP.

Comment: no problem, also you might want to look inside your phonegap projects gradle file and look for a singingConfigs section, then look for the storeFile and copy that .jks file out and put it in your new project